# Postman got 400 , but the cUrl command that generated from postman works

Tags: curl, postman, reverse-proxy

Postman got 400 , but the cUrl command that generated from the postman works.

The cUrl command works as expect, so I believe the request itself has no error.

Target domain is a instant domain of our kubenates, reverse-proxy redirect the request to different service on k8s depend on prefix of the domain.

Looks like the request been redirect to wrong place.

But how is it only happens to postman ?

- Both of postman and the cUrl command execute on my PC.
- Checked proxy setting of postman and command line , no proxy used.
- target is http, so not SSL issue

Comment: Might be use to show the curl request and what the request looks like in Postman and any error messages. At the moment, no one can see what's actually happened.

Comment: You should check with Fidler what is actually being sent when you execute request from postman.